# PHP array_push overwriting the pushed data

Tags: php

I seeing a rare behavior of the array_push php function. It's like when I'm looping through the result rows of the query and pushing the complete array of data into a 'parent' array ($rdo), the values are beeing modified with the ones of the last row added.

This is my code:

```
$rdo = array();

if($sentencia = $general_con->prepare("SELECT monthly_price, name FROM subscription_plan WHERE deleted=0"))
{
    $sentencia->execute();

    $sentencia->store_result();
    $num_of_rows = $sentencia->num_rows;

    $sentencia->bind_result($row['monthly_price'], $row['name']);

    while($sentencia->fetch())
    {
        array_push($rdo, $row);

        echo print_r($rdo,1).'<br/><br/>';
    }
    $sentencia->close();
    die();
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to write `while($row = $sentencia->fetch())`?  Because right now you're not changing `$row` anywhere.

Comment: I think this is due to the way `bind_results()` binds to references. I'm not sure why this is happening, since `array_push()` should make a copy of `$row`.

Comment: @TimRoberts He's changing it with `bind_result()`.

Comment: @TimRoberts like Barmar commented, I'm binding the results into the $row array with bind_results, and then in the while looping throgh the result length to access every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an artifact of the way `bind_result()` uses references to the array elements. When you push `$row` onto `$rdo`, this is updating all those array elements.

I recommend you move away from using `bind_result()` and use `fetch_assoc()`.

```
if($sentencia = $general_con->prepare("SELECT monthly_price, name FROM subscription_plan WHERE deleted=0"))
{
    $sentencia->execute();

    $result = $sentencia->get_result();
    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        array_push($rdo, $row);
        echo print_r($rdo,1).'<br/><br/>';
    }
    $sentencia->close();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this works! I don't know what is the issue with the other way, but this solution works just fine :)